# C# - Handle mouse position with multiple PictureBoxes

Tags: c#, forms, window, picturebox

I created in a **Window Form** 4 PictureBoxes (**pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3** and **pictureBox4**). I also created a function to draw a rectangle on a pictureBox like this:

To create the rectangle:

```
private void PictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var x = e.X;
    var y = e.Y;

    var width = 10;
    var height = 10;

    FwRect = new[]
    {
        new PointF(x, y), new PointF(x, y + height), new PointF(x + width, y + height),
                new PointF(x + width, y)
    };
    FwRectan = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);
    Refresh();
}
```

Then I added this event for each pictureBox:

```
this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.PictureBox_MouseMove);
this.pictureBox2.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.PictureBox_MouseMove);
this.pictureBox3.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.PictureBox_MouseMove);
this.pictureBox4.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.PictureBox_MouseMove);
```

To draw the rectangle:

```
private void PictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
    {
        //Draw the rectangle on our form with the pen
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, FwRectan);
    }
}
```

Eventually, if I move the mouse inside the pictureBox1 and draw a rectangle, it also draw a rectangle for each pictureBox. How can I draw a rectangle only on the pictureBox that the mouse is located at?

[image]
Thank you very much!

Comment: what is FwIsDown, FwDisable and FwStartPointX?

Comment: *"it also draw a rectangle for each pictureBox"* - why? I can't see the answer in code you show, please show more, see [mcve].

Comment: Cast the sender to a picture box and then you can read the text of the box : PictureBox box = sender as PictureBox;

Comment: @Sinatr: I added an image. As you can see, the mouse is at PictureBox1 but the rectangle is drawn for 4 PictureBoxes.

Comment: @jdweng: Can you be more specific please? How can I detect which pictureBox the mouse is located at?

Comment: @TPNguyen, the image is nice, but why is it happening? How rectangle is being painted? Please refer to [mcve].

Comment: @Sinatr: the rectangle is created by taking the mouse location in the pictureBox (e.X and e.Y) with heigh = 10 and width = 10. I then draw it by create a pictureBox_Paint event.

Comment: Did you subscribe all 4 pictureboxes to same `PictureBox_Paint` event handler? Then this happens due to `FwRectan` which value **all** pictureboxes take and paint.

Comment: @Sinatr: yes. But I don't know how to separate them based on the mouse location.

Comment: @jdweng : apparently I can separate them with the name of the pictureBox. But is there a way to do it by mouse location?

Comment: The picturebox has four properties 1) Top 2) Left 3) Height  4) Width   You can check if the mouse location in MouseEventArgs, but the event automatically gives that info.

Comment: Create a custom `PictureBox` to avoid this. Override the `OnPaint` method to draw that rubber-band + the common routines. This way will help you to focus in your implementation on the main problem that you're trying to resolve.

Comment: I would simply test if the mouse is inside the sender's bounds: `if ((sender as PictureBox).Bounds.Contains( (sender as PictureBox).Parent.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition)))`

Answer (score 2):

You have 4 `PictureBox`, so you need 4 `Rectangle` to draw current mouse movement:

```
Rectangle[] _rectangle = new Rectangle[4];
```

then in both common `PictureBox_MouseMove` and `PictureBox_Paint` events you need to identify which value to use, index of picturebox. It can be done by using `Tag` property or by putting all pictureboxes into array so that their index there will match:

```
PictureBox _control = new PictureBox[] { pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, pictureBox4 };
```

The event handles will looks like this

```
void PictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var x = e.X;
    var y = e.Y;

    var width = 10;
    var height = 10;

    FwRect = new[]
    {
        new PointF(x, y), new PointF(x, y + height), new PointF(x + width, y + height),
                new PointF(x + width, y)
    };

    var index = _control.IndexOf(sender);
    _rectangle[index] = new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, (int)width, (int)height);
    _rectangle[index].Invalidate();
}

void PictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var index = _control.IndexOf(sender);
    using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
    {
        //Draw the rectangle on our form with the pen
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _rectangle[index]);
    }
}
```

---

Edit:

Actually above solution will *remember* rectangle for each picturebox. Might not be what you want. The simple fix would be to *clear* other rectangles in mousemove. Though the more proper solution would be to remember `sender` from mousemove and only paint matching `sender` in paint.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example showing how to store the Rectangle in the `.Tag` property as mentioned by Sinatr in his post.  This example also clears the Rectangle when the mouse leaves so you only ever have one Rectangle being drawn in the current PictureBox:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += this.PictureBox_MouseMove;
        this.pictureBox2.MouseMove += this.PictureBox_MouseMove;
        this.pictureBox3.MouseMove += this.PictureBox_MouseMove;
        this.pictureBox4.MouseMove += this.PictureBox_MouseMove;

        this.pictureBox1.MouseLeave += this.pictureBox_MouseLeave;
        this.pictureBox2.MouseLeave += this.pictureBox_MouseLeave;
        this.pictureBox3.MouseLeave += this.pictureBox_MouseLeave;
        this.pictureBox4.MouseLeave += this.pictureBox_MouseLeave;

        this.pictureBox1.Paint += this.PictureBox_Paint;
        this.pictureBox2.Paint += this.PictureBox_Paint;
        this.pictureBox3.Paint += this.PictureBox_Paint;
        this.pictureBox4.Paint += this.PictureBox_Paint;
    }

    private int bxWidth = 10;
    private int bxHeight = 10;
    private void PictureBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        pb.Tag = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, bxWidth, bxHeight);
        pb.Invalidate();
    }

    private void PictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        if (pb.Tag != null && pb.Tag is Rectangle)
        {
            Rectangle rc = (Rectangle)pb.Tag;
            using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 2))
            {
                //Draw the rectangle on our form with the pen
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rc);
            }
        }            
    }

    private void pictureBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = (PictureBox)sender;
        pb.Tag = null; // if you want the box to disappear when the mouse leaves?
        pb.Invalidate();
    }

}
```

Here's what it looks like running:

[image]

Comment: Use [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching). `if (pb.Tag is Rectangle rc) { ... }`.